# PowerBI Report webpart in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, powerbi, sharepoint-server

I have a rather weird problem regarding the SharePoint webpart for paginated reports in PowerBI.
After adding the webpart and configuring it to show a report from the powerbi server, it will work at random.

Most of the time it will work right away with every report I try it with, empty or full of data from SSAS connections.
But after a few minutes or hours, the web part stops working. It just says that there is a problem at the server and I should check the logs on the server but nothing is showing in any log on the powerBi server nor the SharePoint server.
Kerberos is working in the environment (verified by me and a independed consultant) and the reports are working great from the powerbi server itself.

What could cause the report to work for a random period of time in the webpart?